# Will Comparing a Value Against Itself Fail in SQL WHERE Clause

Tags: sql

Question, if someone mistyped a comparison in the AND part of a WHERE clause, so that they ended up comparing a value against itself, would that throw an error, or would it simply fail silently? I ask because I came across a WHERE clause that includes the following line:

```
 WHERE ...
 AND (note_details.id_number = note_details.id_number)
```

How would this be handled?

Comment: Are there any variables used in the code? It would help to see the entire code to be able to tell if what you're seeing was intentional or by mistake.

Comment: I just got confirmation from the person who wrote the code that it was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work.  There is no error.

The logic:

```
where x = x
```

is equivalent to:

```
where x is not null
```

Comment: That's what I thought. But is there a legitimate reason to write this code, or is it likely a typo that was supposed to compare values from two different tables?

Comment: @Banon . . . I can't think of a reason why someone would write this code.  Sometimes, people write something similar, such as `coalesce(x, '') = x`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I checked with the person who originally wrote the query and they realized they had added this check in error.